# PHP cannot assign object parameter values intermittently

Tags: php, object

For some reason PHP cannot assign values to properties of my object intermittently! If I keep refreshing the page it works about 4 times out 5 but on the failed one all the values are not assigned I worked out that the object values are missing.

I have a function to collect a database row and assign it to an object. The query is not the issue the data is being pulled everytime. The issue is to do with this line

```
$obj->$key = str_replace("''","'",$row[$value[0]]);
```

I do a print out to make sure the value is there and then a print out of the object parameter directly after and I can see that all the property values are blank. Not that it is nothing to do with the value itself if I just set the value as a hard coded string the same thing happens

```
$obj->$key = 'a'
```

I don't have this problem with standard variables, the values are always there it just seems that object parameters values cannot be assigned 1 time out 5.

It doesn't seem to be a code related problem since it works 4 times out 5.

```
function getRow($class,$where = false,$order = false, $limit = false) {

    $obj = new $class();

    $sql = "select * from ".$obj->table." where 1 ";

    if ($where) {
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $opvalue = $this->getOperator($value);
            $op = $opvalue[0];
            $value = $opvalue[1];
            if ($obj->cols[$key][1] == 1)
            $sql .= "and ".$obj->cols[$key][0]." $op $value ";
            else if ($obj->cols[$key][1] == 2)
            $sql .= "and ".$obj->cols[$key][0]." $op '$value' ";
        }
    }
    if ($order)
    $sql .= "order by $order ";
    if ($limit)
    $sql .= "limit $limit ";

    $res = $this->runQuery($sql);


    //map values
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


//            print_r($row);

        foreach ($obj->cols as $key => $value) {

            if ($obj->cols[$key][1] == 3) {

                $obj->$key = poststringToArray($row[$value[0]]);

            }
            else {

                $obj->$key = str_replace("''","'",$row[$value[0]]);


//                    echo "obj->$key  = {$row[$value[0]]}<br>";
//
//                    echo "obj->$key = ".$obj->$key.'<br>';



            }

        }
//            echo '<p>';
//            print_r($obj);
//            echo '</p>';

    }
    else {

        return false;

    }




    return $obj;
}
```

Forget about the complex code above here's a simple example where the property value will be blank missing intermittently, but the variable retains the value. If I keep refreshing this script the value of 'id' will be blank sometimes!

```
Class SalesOrderService {

var $id;

}
$test = 'a string';

echo 'the value of $test is \''.$test."'";

echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';

$so = new SalesOrderService();

$so->id = 'aaa';

print_r($so);
```

Comment: @Daedalus: He's setting the key dynamically. $object->$key = 'A'; would set the value of $object->id if $key = 'id', for example.

Comment: @ParhamDoustdar Didn't see it documented anywhere; but it does work, so, deleting my comment.

Comment: I might add that the same problem occurs for hardcoded keys not just dynamic ones so for example $obj->key would not keep the value sometimes also

Comment: Are you using StdClass?

Comment: nope I'm not, see the last example

Comment: ok I found this in the logs "Attempt to assign property of non-object" meaning the object doesn't exist! I have PHP 5.3.3 and starting to find a few similar posts now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a bug in 5.3 I upgraded to 5.4 and it works fine now